# iCloud only syncs after App terminates

Tags: ios, sandbox, icloud

My iOS app is using iCloud to keep docs in sync with an OS X version. This works fine almost.

The problem is that the device iCloud sandbox is only synced after the application terminates and as my app will stay open in background as long as its not shutdown by the system this raises the likelihood of having document conflicts between either client.

I have tried calling

```
NSError *error = NULL;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:downloadfile error:&error];
```

When the app goes to background, as the docs claim

> If a cloud-based file or directory has not been downloaded
>   yet, calling this method starts the download process. If the item
>   exists locally, calling this method synchronizes the local copy with
>   the version in the cloud.

Any ideas on how to force the sync while the app is still open?